# Kafka Connect frequently check for new connectors

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to frequently check if there are new connectors uploaded directly in the specified plugin path of a Kafka Connect cluster?

What I want to achieve is, to upload connector jar files directly inside the pod without recreating the image and redeploying the connect cluster every time I have changes in the connector jar. I've been doing a lot of testing and I want to save time by avoiding re-deploying the cluster and re-creating the image every time I have changes.

I'm trying to catch scenarios that can only happen on the actual cluster instead of the sandbox (local docker-compose cluster).

Comment: You can `volume` the plugin dir outside the docker to inside. This will help avoiding building a new image. Once a new plugin is set, you have to restart the kafka-connect. This is guess to be done by outer script watching the dir, and once a plugin pops, restarts the `kafka connect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pick up the new connector plugin, you have to restart the Kafka Connect worker.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I ended up doing an init container in the kafka connect cluster that downloads the jar files from the artifactory and store it in volume. The image rebuild has been eliminated so I just have to restart the cluster for changes.